# Сумма значений столбца при условии

Tags: sql

Как посчитать сумму по столбцу при одинаковых значениях другого столбца?

То есть, для всех `a` посчитать сумму по полю `С`, для всех `b` по полю `С` и так далее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие попытки решения задачи были предприняты?

Answer (score 5):

Для этого существует группировка ([GROUP BY](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_group_by_clause.html)).

UPD

```
Select SUM(с) from table Group By a
```

Comment: Я дал ссылку. Там упомянуто. :-)

Comment: Это я зря не проверил. По поводу правки вопроса (не знаю почему её утвердили): `SELECT SUM(с), a FROM table GROUP BY a` будет более информативно.